# DataPicker Button influenced by a global styling on all Buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm maintaining a big old C#/WPF application in which a style has been set globally for all buttons It can sound ugly, but I can't change this without refactoring the whole app.

Here is an extract of this style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="96"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

The problem is that when I want to use a DatePicker, this global style influenced the appearance of the DataPicker:

[image]

Is there a *simple* way to restore the default Margin, Height and MinWidth **only for the Button inside the DatePicker**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `Style` for the `Button`s locally.  The following `XAML` sets the `Style` for all `Button`s inside the `DatePicker` back to the default `Style`.

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <!-- Default Style --> 
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

---

**Edit**

As requested in the comments, a `Style` to fix this issue globally

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Note: This `Style` should be placed in the same hierarchy-context as the `Button` `Style`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there a way to set this for all the DatePickers at once?